local conda enviroment the pip installs now use global pip
I keep my conda environments local to each vscode project.  In a current project I require libraries not curated by conda and have installed pip via a conda install.  This environment had been functioning perfectly fine for some time.  Recently I upgraded mac os to Big Sur and was testing out Zsh and during one of those steps I have broken the environment connections with the pip installs.  Pip now doesn't install to the local activated environment it installs to the global environment.  I assure you the vscode terminal and the project both are pointing to the same correct interpretter and activated env. The resulting issue is any libraries pip installs will not be recognized and throw module not found errors when running the scripts.
This Post has been very helpful but has not quite solved my challenge.
I created a new local environment assuming that a reset would likely correct the issue but with a newly generated env
`rafe$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/Users/rafe2.2/local_vscode_path/data_env_new/bin/python
rafe$ which -a pip
/usr/bin/python/bin/pip
/Users/rafe2.2/local_vscode_path/data_env_new/bin/pip`
I think this indicates the project is now prioritizing the global spaces rather than the local ones.  I assume that because in a other fulling working vscode workspaces the order is reversed. My question is how can I change this behaviour because I suspect that from here on in any new environments that I build will follow this pattern.
Any recommendations on how to solve and what could have happened would be most appreciated. TIA
I can successfully solve the basic issue of installing pip packages with (thanks to above post):
/Users/rafe2.2/local_vscode_path/data_env_new/bin/pip install mockito.
